# unable to compare two floating point variables in awk?

Tags: shell, awk

I am trying to compare two variables containing decimal values in an if statement in `awk script` inside a `shell script` like

```
#Shell script code
...
$weight=31.33
awk -v val=$weight '{if($NF > weight){print;}}' weight_chart.txt 

#weight_chart.txt#
johny    12    35.45
jenny    16    38.23
Tomu     8     29.12
...
...
```

The output should be something like

```
johny    12    35.45
jenny    16    38.23
```

But the output prints all the lines of the file weight_chart.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making many mistakes.

1. Shell vars don't start with `$`
2. You're naming awk variable as `val` but using `weight` in awk script

Try this:

```
> weight=31.33
> awk -v val=$weight '$NF > val' weight_chart.txt
johny    12    35.45
jenny    16    38.23
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava,thanks for the response but it still doesn't work , it isnt printing anything at all :P

Comment: You can see corrected command and their output in my answer itself.